# Unable to terminate a running program / application

Tags: terminal, exit, application

I am having trouble terminating applications started from the terminal - for example, I used:
cd /usr/bin and ls to determine that the gimp app is here.

I then started gimp by typing "gimp" - started successfully.

BUT, I cant stop / exit the program.  There is no "$" sign from which to start (indicating that the process is running, I suppose).

I have tried: (gimp:23558): GEGL-gegl-operation.c-WARNING **: Cannot change name of operation class 0x29DFB70 from "gimp:point-layer-mode" to "gimp:anti-erase-mode"

kill
pwd
kill
exit
q
quit
Q
QUIT
TERM
SIGTERM

None of these work - neither would I expect them to because there is no "$" sign to begin from.

Comment: To clarify, when you say you started gimp from a terminal, do you mean you ssh-ed into a computer and typed in gimp in that ssh session?  Or you logged into a computer using a GUI, brought up a terminal and typed gimp in that terminal window?

Comment: Hi - am running Ubuntu 16.  I booted up into this and then opened a terminal.  I then opened gimp from the terminal.

Comment: I see someone down-voted my question - indicating their belief that I showed "no research effort".  On the contrary - I have been trying to solve this for weeks - combing the internet and literature - no one could give the answer - coming up with very complex solutions yet, in the end, it is simple.  Please note, I am 69 years old and trying to learn Linux - trust me, not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand but is it a case of "ctrl+C" to terminate the current program returning you to the shell prompt ($)?

Comment: PERFECT - worked perfectly!  Many many thanks - most grateful for your patience!

Comment: Funny - I tried to upvote your answer but it will not accept it.  Strange.

Comment: @user6542 you can accept this as answer fyi.

Answer (score 0):

Gimp (and others) will terminate with a Ctrl-C.

If you want to recover the command prompt, you can also use Ctrl-Z, which stops the current process (but doesn't terminate it) and returns to the shell prompt.

- If you want the stopped process to continue running, in the background, enter `bg`.
- If you want to resume the process in the foreground, enter `fg`

For more resilient processes, you can open another terminal (or tab) and use `pkill {processname}`, for instance `pkill gimp`. Note that the argument is a regex pattern (so for instance `gimp` could another process with `gimp` in its name) so use with caution. Normally no process can resist the `-9` option, so use with extreme caution.

For GUI apps, there is another method: strike <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd>: the cursor changes into a skull and bones, move it over a window of the process you want to kill and click or strike <kbd>Enter</kbd> to kill it. If you change your mind just hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to return to the normal cursor. Also use with caution, if you click the background this will kill the desktop shell.

Comment: Thank you very much - greatly appreciated. DB